# Number of Network Connections in Android

Tags: android, networking, android-asynctask

1. Is there any limit for Android Network Connections?
2. If we want to limit the number of network connections running in the background, how can we achieve it?
3. If we start a network connection in AsyncTask and if we cancel it by using `AsyncTask_object.cancel(true)`, Will it close all the corresponding internal network connections?
4. How to cancel running Network Connection in Android ?

Comment: By Network Connections, do you mean specific connections, for example, to google.com or do you mean ***all*** connections including not only the ones you opened in your program but also all connections other applications have opened?

Comment: @jedwards only the connections opened by my program.

Comment: Then certainly don't disable the network interface as suggested by shk.schneider.  Is there some reason you can't keep track of the connections you open and go through and close them?  Usually there is a `.close()` for example [the close() method for Sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the limits are, since it's Linux-based.

3.

I think you should check with the `onCancelled(Object)` method.

4.

Suppose we do this:
`ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

This should close the connection: `connec.getNetworkInfo(0).setState(NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED);`

Also take a look at
http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-proper-way-to-cancel-asynctask/

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Am waiting for few more answers.

Comment: I believe that setting the network state to disconnected might have more effects than the OP intended -- specifically closing ***all*** network connections.

Comment: The point here is `setState(NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED)` and `onCancelled()`. `connec.getNetworkInfo(0)` is just an example connection.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your 3rd question:

Calling AsyncTask_object.cancel(true) will not close the internal connections, instead it will call a callback method onCancelled() of AsyncTask class. So, its your reponsibility to write code in onCancelled() that will cancel/rollback all the work that is being done in AsyncTask. You can call isCancelled() to know whether task is calcelled or not.

Example:

```
if(task.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
  task.cancel(true);
```

In AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
//cancell/rollback the work being done
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that we should close the connection just like in the the answer given by shk.schneider below?

Comment: Yes, not only connection other things like removing local cache when downloading a file, etc.,